# QUERY LEFT JOIN - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Olá,
Vejam esta query:

```
SELECT `permission`.`visible`, `menu`.* 
  FROM `tb_permission` `permission` 
  LEFT JOIN `tb_menu` as `menu` ON `menu`.`id` = `permission`.`menu_id` 
 WHERE `permission`.`visible` = 1 
   AND `permission`.`type` = 0 
    OR `permission`.`type` = 1 
   AND `permission`.`role_id` = '1' 
 ORDER BY `menu`.`id` ASC
```

Agora vejam o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não deveria vir somente resultados, cujo campo `visible` é igual a 1 ?

Comment: *"Não deveria vir somente resultados, cujo campo visible é igual a 1"*, veja se o `or` da sua query não está trazendo resultados indesejados

Comment: @RicardoPontual, Sim, está! Se eu remover, consigo ver os resultados corretos, eu retirei o `or`, e troquei por `!= 2` e deu certo.. obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `permission`.`visible`, `menu`.* 
  FROM `tb_permission` `permission` 
  LEFT JOIN `tb_menu` as `menu` ON `menu`.`id` = `permission`.`menu_id` 
 WHERE `permission`.`visible` = 1 
   AND `permission`.`type`in (0,1) 

   AND `permission`.`role_id` = '1' 
 ORDER BY `menu`.`id` ASC
```

testa assim, deve tá caindo nesse OR

Answer (score 2):

O problema está nas condições do `WHERE` na sua query. Quando combinar condições `AND` com `OR` é sempre melhor usar parênteses para definir bem o que quer. Veja esta Thread no SO que fala sobre a prioridade das condições em uma query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4872213/7380348

No caso está indo os resultados do `type = 1` também. Não está mostrando nos resultados que postou para ter certeza mas acredito que seja isso.

Para resolver isto, faça: `... WHERE visible = 1 AND (type = 0 OR type = 1) AND role_id = 1...`

Answer (score 1):

Como já foi citado, o OR da sua query deve estar gerando os problemas, procure sempre utilizar a condição OR entre parentes:

```
SELECT `permission`.`visible`, `menu`.* 
  FROM `tb_permission` `permission` 
  LEFT JOIN `tb_menu` as `menu` ON `menu`.`id` = `permission`.`menu_id` 
 WHERE `permission`.`visible` = 1 
   AND ( `permission`.`type` = 0 OR `permission`.`type` = 1 )
   AND `permission`.`role_id` = '1' 
 ORDER BY `menu`.`id` ASC
```